# unable to change the input background based on condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

here below is my JSON data

```
data = {
    name: 'paul',
    author: '',
    country: '',
    id: 7465
};
```

here by using the above data, I am displaying the input  and label

```
 <label class="inline-label" for="{{data.name}}">{{data.name}}</label>
```

for input

```
<input id="{{data.name}}" type="{{data.details.type}}" style=" border-radius:0;" class="form-control error">
```

here my issue is

1. I unable to display the input background color based on condition when the input value is empty  only for selected one I have other input also it is based on other than I don't want to change

below is the code I have tried

```
if (data['author'] === '') {
    $('.error').css('background-color', '#fff');
    $('.error')
        .filter(function() {
            return $.trim(this.value) === '';
        })
        .css('border-bottom:', '1px solid #FF0000 !important');
} else {
    $('.error').css({ 'background-color': 'green' });
}
```

Comment: are you use angular form like reactive form or template form  ??

Comment: i am not using those as this has already developed with out using those thats why

Comment: I would suggest you to maybe set certain classes with styles that you expect when eg. author property is empty or not. Then instead of jQuery use it in HTML like ``<input [class]="someCondition ? 'class1':'class2'">``

Comment: You can easily target input validation state like invalid input , touched by css only @Jibin

Comment: i tried the [ngStyle] approach but didnt worked

Comment: @malbarmawi there are 2 types of input's i am using one using the above json data and creating and another input with another json data both  are mixed up here thats, why is there any possibilty that i can check only those json data which i mentioned or can i check whether key has empty pair value or not

Comment: Are you using angular for this case?

Comment: @Mat.Now  yeah angular & jquery i am not using any reactive or template approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this input background color will be red if the name is falsy like empty string

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="name" [ngStyle]="{'background-color': !name ?'#f00' : '#fff'}" />
```

Check author proprty

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="data.author" [ngStyle]="{'background-color': !data.author ?'#f00' : '#fff'}" />
```

> I will recommend to use angular form you can easy set the style of invalid inputs and **don't use jquery**

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kdgbsm)

Comment: could u tell me how can i check whether a key is having value or not i mean empty

Comment: do you mean like this data.author @Jibin ?

Comment: I have updated the answer for checking author @Jibin

Comment: yeah what i did was Object.keys(data).map(k => data[k])  this is retrieving  keys now if i can check  data['author']=='' using loops then i can find a solution i think so here i need to check whether data['author'] is empty or not

Comment: I have update the stackbliz like sorry was linked to wrong url can you check now @Jibin

Comment: my bad i already have [(ngModel)] so i cant bind the 2 model names right can i use template binding

Comment: ngModel for update the value of the input you can use property binding [value] ="data.author"

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure if this is what you are looking for, but you can change the background color of the input field based in some condition like this:

StackBlitz example: [Change background based on condition](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-juvztp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

HTML file:

```
<label class="inline-label" for="{{data.name}}">{{data.name}}</label>

<input [(ngModel)]="input" name="input" type="text" id="{{data.name}}" [class.inputColor]="input">
```

TS file:

```
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';

  input;

   data = {
    "name":'paul',
    "author":'',
    "country":'',
    "id":7465 ,
  }
}
```

CSS file:

```
.inputColor {
  background-color: blue;
  caret-color: white;
  color: white;
}
```

In this case the background color changes to blue and the letters to white when the input field is not empty.

To your second question, how to check if in a pair-value object the value field is empty you can do the following:

```
  object = {
    key: 'A',
    value: ''
  }

  isValueEmpty(object) {
    if (!object.value) return true;
    else return false;
  }
```

Comment: But this is not working ? & i already have some other [(ngModel)]

Comment: @Jibin the StackBlitz example is working fine. And what do you mean with other [(ngModel)]?

Comment: i  unable to see the background color any thing>

Comment: In the example if you type in the input field the background color of the input should change to blue.

Comment: could u tell me how can i check whether a key is having value or not i mean empty

Comment: Do you mean how to determine when a key is pressed?

Comment: Object key value pair

Comment: I think I dont understant your question. Could you give an example?

Comment: see if i have  {''a":"aklsjdkladj","b":''"}  can i check whether b is having a empty value or not  with out mentioning the key name dynamically can we check

Comment: @Jibin Im not sure if this is what you ask for but check question edit.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Angular's ngClass binding to achieve this.

Data sample (.ts Service file returning Observable data):

```
  public items = [
    { "name":'paul', "author":'  ', "country":'', "id":7465 },
    { "name":'Jibin', "author":'JQuery', "country":'', "id":7466 }
  ];
```

Controller sample (.ts file to map another flag field):

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

public items = [];
private unsubData = new Subject<void>();

ngOnInit() {
    this.service.dataUpdated
    .takeUntil(this.unsubData)
    .map((data: any) => {
      data.forEach(element => {
        element.flgEmpty = (element['author'].trim() === '') ? true : false;
      });
      return data;
    })
    .subscribe((data: any) => {
      console.log(data);
      this.items = data;
    });
}

ngOnDestroy() {
    this.unsubData.next();
    this.unsubData.complete();
}
```

HTML sample (.html file):

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items">
  <label class="inline-label" for="{{item.name}}">{{item.name}}</label>
  <input id="{{item.name}}" type="text" [ngClass]="[item.flgEmpty ? 'form-control error' : 'form-control success']">
</div>
```

CSS sample (.css file):

```
.form-control { border-radius:0;}
.error {border-bottom: 1px solid #FF0000;}
.success {background-color: green;}
```

Comment: could u tell me how can i check whether a key is having value or not i mean empty

Comment: Assuming that you are receiving this data from back end, you must be receiving it as Observable/Subject. You need to use rxjs's operator 'map' and add another field to your JSON to check JSON's dynamic property value. For example (.ts file):

Comment: I edited my original example to explain the implementation. In short, you need to use 'map' to check dynamic JSON name. It can not be checked directly into .html view.

Answer (score 1):

you can use something like this which does not include jquery

```
.white-background{
background-color
}

`<input id="{{data.name}}" [class.white-background]="!data.author" type="`{{data.details.type}}" style=" border-radius:0;" class="form-control error">
```